# Ms Access: Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on [table]

Tags: ms-access, permissions, oledb, database-permissions

i wrote script for downloading mdb files and reading them due OLEDB provider. All works fine, but if i try to read from table, it throws an exception:

**Ms Access: Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on tblMytable**

```
 var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblMytable", conn);
 var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I changed permissions directly in Ms Access for user "administrator" and it works. But the problem is, that this script musst run twice a day and it downloads about 20 files. So its impossible manually changing permissions.

**Is it possible to change read rights for a table programatically?**

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: Not sure if you CAN change the rights, but if possible, it will require that you log into db as a user with Admins or Owner permission. So I would suggest that instead you try to directly login as such a user, perhaps by changing you connection string. i suspect that you will need the .MDW file for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by using system.mdw file. I copied this file from "c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\" (in Win7) to application directory (App_Data) and modified connection string.

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.MDB;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:System Database=|DataDirectory|\System.MDW;
```

`var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);`

If still it's impossible to read data, i execute grant command:

```
"GRANT SELECT ON TABLE tblTable TO PUBLIC"
```

And it works :)