# How do I give myself read permission for a local Access table?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access, server-explorer

I'm trying to see if my SQL statement (MS Access) does what it should in Visual Studio by creating a connection to it and then running the query in the Server Explorer.

I want to find out if there's any difference between these two queries:

```
SELECT        duckbill_.id, duckbill_.pack_size, duckbill_.description, duckbill_.vendor_id, duckbill_.department, duckbill_.subdepartment, duckbill_.unit_cost, duckbill_.unit_list, duckbill_.open_qty, duckbill_.UPC_code, 
                         duckbill_.UPC_pack_size, duckbill_.crv_id, duckbill__vendors.vendor_item
FROM            duckbill_, duckbill__vendors
WHERE        (duckbill_.vendor_id = duckbill__vendors.vendor_id)
```

and:

```
SELECT        duckbill_.id, duckbill_.pack_size, duckbill_.description, duckbill_.vendor_id, duckbill_.department, duckbill_.subdepartment, duckbill_.unit_cost, duckbill_.unit_list, duckbill_.open_qty, duckbill_.UPC_code, 
                         duckbill_.UPC_pack_size, duckbill_.crv_id, duckbill__vendors.vendor_item
FROM            (duckbill_ LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         duckbill__vendors ON duckbill_.vendor_id = duckbill__vendors.vendor_id)
```

...but it won't even let me execute the query. I can connect to the database, but apparently not to the individual tables. I get this error:

```
*SQL Execution Error
<My SQL statement>
Error Message: Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'duckbill_'.*
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Here is a link to this question, answered.  Ms Access: Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on [table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361259/ms-access-records-cannot-be-read-no-read-permission-on-table

Comment: I don't believe this is the same question, as that question states specifically: "Is it possible to change read rights for a table programatically?" I did not want to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still wanted to do this in Visual Studio's server explorer (or any other Jet query tool). Here's what I did to fix it:

1. Shift + double click the mdb file
2. Go to the Database Tools tab
3. Click Users and Permissions > User and Group Permissions

   - If no users show up here, you may first need to visit Users and Permissions > User and Group Accounts to create one.
4. Select the `Admin` user which I connect with
5. Under "Object Name:" click the top item, then shift click the last table to select them all
6. Click all permissions check boxes (or the read-only ones, if you prefer)
7. Apply; close Access.

Now Visual Studio's Server Explorer was able to connect and run queries under the "Admin" user.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what I need to do:

```
Won) In Windows Explorer, hold shift and 2-click the MDB you want to work with.
Too) In Access, select Objects | Queries, then "Create query in Design view"
3) Close the "Show table" dialog
Fore) Right-click in the pane and select "SQL View"
```

You now have a blank canvas on which to "do your damage"